# How to mix a densities functions and a time series graph

Tags: r, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

Is there a way to plot densities over a time series?  I'm looking for something like this:
[image: a MS Paint drawing of what I want]

Comment: Post some data, and show what you have tried. [In other words](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [check this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Claus Wilke has [some great examples of exactly this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/gallery.html) in the vignettes of the [ggridges package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/).  Here's a reproducible one illustrating how it's done:

```
library(ggridges)
library(ggplot2movies)

ggplot(movies[movies$year>1912,], aes(x = length, y = year, group = year)) +
  geom_density_ridges(scale = 10, size = 0.25, rel_min_height = 0.03) +
  theme_ridges() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, 200), expand = c(0.01, 0)) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks=c(2000, 1980, 1960, 1940, 1920, 1900), expand = c(0.01, 0))
```

## Film Lengths by Year

[image]